# How can I create Solr Instance

Tags: instance, solr

I am new to Apache Solr, and I want to create Solr instances. I have configured the Apache Solr 3.2.0 locally in my laptop. How I can create Solr Instance and what is the meaning of Solr Instance. Any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 3):

> what is the meaning of Solr Instance

An solr-instance is something like an runtime-environment. It's an running solr service. U use Solr to work with lucene.
Lucene are java libraries to create/access/... the fulltext index, no instance, no running system.
To contact/use this indexed data (import/export/search/...) , you need an "mediator" or "agent" like solr. Solr can index or access the indexed data by using lucene.

Example: if you have an laptop or pc. So the running (linux/win) system is an instance, while the data from the systems is stored on hard disk.

Solr is comparable with the running system, lucene is comparable with the disk-dirver to store data on your system-drive.

To get an definition of what an instance is, check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instance_%28computer_science%29

> How I can create Solr Instance

by starting the tomcat server, which runs the Solr J2EE component.
So if your Solr is still configured, start the tomcat for starting/creating an solr-instance.

In general, this link is helpful: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat

Comment: No. Lucene is a Java library to create and manage indices. It's not just "data as an index".

Comment: Oh sorry, I expressed misleading/wrong. I will correct my answer with your with consideration. Thank you for this comment.

Comment: thanks for the information.. I started the solr with the Tomcat Server and I have few fields that I have to create so that I can index them to Solr.. for the time being I am indexing all the xml doc that are in example directory. So how I can create those fields and few of them are multivalued fields..

Comment: Are you familiar with the schema.xml? http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml there you define the fields. After changing, you have to restart the solr instance.